# TJSONObject.AddPair not working in Delphi Alexandria 11.2 on Android device

Tags: json, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria

In Delphi Alexandria 11.2, I'm trying to parse JSON with some text from FMX component values.

The code is very basic, but I'm not getting the desired result. I suspect a major bug in the product.

```pascal
// Create User object
oUser := TUser.Create;
// Fill the User object
oUser.FirstName := edFirstname.Text;
oUser.LastName := edLastname.Text;
oUser.DateOfBirth := StrToDate(edDateOfBirth.Text);
//oUser.Gender := cbGender.Items.Text;
oUser.Location := edLocation.Text;
//oUser.PhoneCountry := cbPhoneCountry.Items.Text;
oUser.PhoneNumber := edPhoneNumber.Text;
oUser.Email := edEmailAddress.Text;
oUser.Password := edPassword.Text;

vJSON := TJSONObject.Create;
vJSON.AddPair('FirstName', edFirstname.Text);
vJSON.AddPair('LastName', edLastname.Text);
vJSON.AddPair('DateOfBirth', '19/02/1990');
vJSON.AddPair('Gender', 'Société');
vJSON.AddPair('Location', edLocation.Text);
vJSON.AddPair('PhoneId', 'FR');
vJSON.AddPair('PhoneNumber', edPhoneNumber.Text);
vJSON.AddPair('Email', edEmailAddress.Text);
vJSON.AddPair('Password', edPassword.Text);

vTmpString := vJSON.ToString;
```

When I deploy on Android and debug the `vJSON.ToString` value, I find nothing in it.

[image]

When I change the target platform to Windows with the exactly same code, I get the desired JSON.

So, I'm thinking there is a bug in the `TJSONObject.AddPair()` routine when the deploy target is Android.

Can someone please give a try with Delphi Alexandria 11.2 and tell me what is wrong?

Comment: I would suggest inspecting `vJSON` itself to make sure `AddPair()` is actually working. You are relying on the debugger's evaluation of calling `ToString()` (why not `vTmpString`?). It looks like perhaps the evaluator window may be treating the output as if it were 8-bit text rather than the 16-bit Unicode text. Have you tried simply displaying `vTmpString` in your UI at runtime instead, such as with `ShowMessage()` or `TEdit.Text` or anything like that? If you really are ending up with `vTmpString='{'` then `ToString` itself is at fault and should be reported to Embarcadero.

Comment: Hi Remy, thank you for the answer.
Both vTempString or vJSONToString give the same result on the debugger.
After a try to display vTmpString on a TMemo in the UI, I got the same result : '{'.

I tried all these instructions without success : 
Memo.lines.add(vTempString)
Memo.lines.add(vJSON.ToString)
Memo.lines.add(vJSON.ToJSON) (found on a Embarcadero TJSONObject example page)

All gave the same result : '{' in Android but the "Memo.lines.add(vJSON.ToString)" gave me the desired JSON on Windows target.

Comment: Well, you have not ruled out the possibility that `AddPair()` may be at fault yet, so I strongly suggest you *verify* whether `AddPair()` is actually working or failing. Inspect the `TJSONObject` itself - does its `Count` increase? Can you access the pairs using `vJSON.Pairs[]` and `vJSON.Values[]`? In any case, the implementation of `AddPair()` is very simple compared to `ToString()`, which is much more complex. And the fact that the output has `{` but not `}`. So I would suspect a bug in how `ToString()` prepares its output. Do you have the same problem with `vJSON.ToJSON()` as well?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this however I always use json writers. It's more work but I like it: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Rio/en/RTL.JSONWriter

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Android with 11.3. `System.JSON` didn't change between 11.2 and 11.3 so chances that `AddPair` or `ToString` is not working in 11.2 and is working for me in 11.3 due to some other RTL code involved are minimal. Your screen snapshot and parts of the code posted here (`oUser`) suggest that you are running this as part of existing application. You need to create proper [mcve] just using code related to constructing `vJSON` and converting it to string. If that works in brand new application, then the issue is in some other code you haven't posted here.

Comment: If code does not work in brand new application, then most likely issue was resolved in 11.3 so you might need to update Delphi. It is also possible that issue appears because of specific data you are using, so you may want to update this question with actual data use in `AddPair`, and not using content on edit controls we cannot inspect.